# Can't create a model object on a paho mqtt message callback

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm using python to work with mqtt,I'm a newbie at this but paho library has been working great.
What i have not been able to acheive is to create a model object on message callback.
The logic behind this is whenever topic listens to somemthing It will validate the msg, after  validation it'll be creating an object, but for some reason that doesn't happen, I've put some prints to check if it's going inside the callback function, and inside if statement and It does, however I can't get the object to be saved. It's like it was ignoring the sentence.

This is my class:

```
class currentConsumer(APIView):
    def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):
        print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.qos)+" "+str(msg.payload))
        if (float(msg.payload)>=10):
            e = SwitchEvents(aerator=1, switch_type=1)
            e.save()

        else:
            e = SwitchEvents(aerator_id=1, switch_type=0)
            e.save()

    mqttc = mqtt.Client(transport='websockets')  
    mqttc.username_pw_set(username=MQTT_USERNAME, password=MQTT_PASSWORD) 
    mqttc.on_message = on_message
    mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
    mqttc.on_publish = on_publish
    mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

    mqttc.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, 60)

    mqttc.subscribe("/SENSOR/+/CORRIENTE", 0)
    #mqttc.subscribe("$SYS/#", 0)

    mqttc.loop_forever()
```

I didn't paste here the other functions (on connect, on_publish, etc) because didn't find them necessary.
I've been thinking that create methods don't work inside this kind of functions, but really don't know. There are no errors, nothing.

Any advice will be helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Wrap the whole of strategy in a try/expect block and print any caught errors

Comment: Awesome @hardillb ! 
I did that, and it bring an exception, the problem was that I wanted to assign an int value to a foreign key field that needed an instance, thank you so much!